# How do I in MySQL organize groups of hierarchical data from a single table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data

I'm attempting to make a MySQL query that will group hierarchical data.  Here is an example of the database

```
table name: location
locationID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
parentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name CHAR(255)
```

*and here is some example data*

```
 locationID    parentID     name
 1      |     0     |   United States
 2      |     1     |   Massachusetts
 3      |     2     |   Boston
 4      |     2     |   Worcester
 5      |     1     |   New York
 6      |     5     |   Brooklyn
 7      |     1     |   Colorado
 8      |     7     |   Denver
 9      |     0     |   Canada
 10     |     9     |   Ontario
 11     |     10    |   Toronto
 12     |     9     |   Quebec
 13     |     12    |   Quebec City
```

The above names are just examples to understand how I wish to process the query.
I wish to display the above table data in a specific way.
I want rows where parentID = 0 to be ordered by name ascending (countries), and under each of those, list rows where parentID matches the locationID (states/provinces), and under each of those rows, list rows where parentID matches the locationID (cities).

This is what I've tried so far, to no avail.

```
SELECT locationID,parentID,name FROM location ORDER BY parentID ASC name ASC
```

as well as

```
SELECT locationID,parentID,name FROM location GROUP BY 'parentID' ORDER BY name ASC
```

I want to be able to add rows and choose a parent and have a list generated that has the parent on top, then the children underneath and the children's children underneath each child, etc.  I'm programming in MySQL and PHP

Any suggestions on tackling this would be most helpful and appreciated, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Self join the thing with aliases. Not that that sheds complete clarity probably ;)

Comment: You want this done purely in mysql? Or PHP with mysql?

Comment: Preferably in MySQL, but if PHP is necessary / safer and or faster, then both I guess.

Comment: So I successfully designed a working PHP version of what I want, however it uses numerous queries within WHILE loops inside each other. Not very efficient or as fast as I would want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table location
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    parentId int not null, -- avoid nulls, 0 is top-level
    place varchar(100) not null
);

insert location(parentId,place) values (0,'Canada'),(0,'Mass'),(0,'Jersey');

insert location(parentId,place) values (2,'Boston'),(2,'Newton'),(2,'Woods Hole');

insert location(parentId,place) values (5,'Chestnut Hill');

insert location(parentId,place) values (3,'Montclair'),(3,'Secaucus');


-- get first level children
select t1.*,t2.*
from location t1
join location t2
on t2.parentId=t1.id and t1.place='Mass'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your DB design is wrong, thereby making it tricky to query the data as required so it can be formatted as desired.

Consider three tables:

```
Country with columns:- name,country_ID
State with columns:- name, state ID, country ID
City with columns:- name, city_ID (maybe not needed) state_ID.
```

With this design the query almost talks to you.

Comment: What is meant by "Not flexible design"?

Comment: If there is a desire for new levels of hierarchy such as country, region, province, neighborhood , street ... then you need to re-schema and change source code. As opposed to simply re-adjusting parent data. Not to mention the clutter you have created and poor performance.